# How to parse data in the formatted of array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, arraylist

I am building an Android application where a user selects images
 like choose your favorite food that is displayed in ImageButton.

Now when I click on this ImageButton it Should be add to an array list
 and this array list should be parse to a define API. How should I add a string in array and parse it?

Here is my code showing ImageButton functionality :-

```
    img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hotdog);
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             isClicked1=!isClicked1;
                if (isClicked1) {
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotdog1);
                    start();
                    jArray.put("Bowling");

                }else {
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotdog);
                }

        }
    });

    img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
    img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice);
    img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            isClicked2=!isClicked2;
            if (isClicked2) {
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice1);
                start();
            }else {
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice);
            }
        }
    });
```

When the isClicked2 function is called the string ice should be added
 in an array and at last on submitted button click this array should be
 parsed to an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
img2.setTag(String.valueOf("R.drawable.ice"));
```

and take it with

```
img2.getTag();
```

**Update 2**

to put just "ice" or "hotdog"

-use set tag after you set the image resource

-get the last drawable part and insert to list:

```
String[] splitted = String.valueOf(img.getTag()).split(".");
if(splitted.length > 0) {
    myList.add(splitted[splitted.length];
}
```

**Full Code**

```
img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice);
img2.setTag(String.valueOf("R.drawable.ice");
img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        isClicked2=!isClicked2;
        if (isClicked2) {
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice1);
            String[] splitted = String.valueOf(img.getTag()).split(".");

            if(splitted.length > 0) {
                myList.add(splitted[splitted.length];
            }

            start();
        }else {
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please tell me how can I add it in array

Comment: If you are using an ArrayList<String> just do myList.put(img2.getTag());

Comment: Can you please tell me this img2.setTag(String.valueOf("R.drawable.ice")); this will be add image in the array but I need to add in String like ice-creame

Comment: Thanks!! let me try it as I am new to How to use it! can you please help me in detail by giving an example.. I will be very thanks full to u!!

Comment: Thank a lot! can you please help me to resolving this error - myList cannot be resolved. What I do ? should I make local variable of it ?

Comment: can I delete this string on else condition from the array ?

Comment: sure you can with myList.remove(img2.getTag());

Comment: Thank a lot! can you please help me to resolving this error - myList cannot be resolved. What I do ? should I make local variable of it ? please guide me

Comment: can You please tell me how can I toast the value of array to check the code is working good and correct!

Comment: Create a field for the list. Could you please accept the answer?

Comment: How to make field of list please help me for this last query then please let me accept your question

Comment: Outside of oncreate ArrayList<String> myList;

Comment: On put it is coming an error - The method put(String) is undefined for the type ArrayList<String> please guide me

Comment: OK thanks for this correction let me try and accept your answer.